# modify url by clicking a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page in php, and I'm trying to add an ?id=variable_value extension to it's url when I click on a div, but when I click it gives me an undefined url error with the extension

Here is the script:

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var Pokemon_ID = 1;
    
    function changeUrl() {
        location.href=this.href+'?id='+Pokemon_ID;return false;
    }
    
    document.getElementById( 'right-btn' ).onclick = function() {
        changeUrl();
    };

</script>
```

And the div :

```html
<div id="right-btn" href="pokedex.php" onclick="changeUrl()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use two separate ways of attaching handlers when you only need one. Inline event handlers are essentially `eval` inside HTML markup - they're bad practice and result in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead.

The problem is that when assigning the handler via `onclick`, the `this` in `changeUrl` is undefined, because the calling context is global. Feel free to avoid using `this` when it can cause confusion.

Just use `addEventListener` alone. Also, you'll have to use `getAttribute('href')` instead of `.href` because `div`s are not supposed to have `href` properties.

```js
const Pokemon_ID = '5';
document.getElementById('right-btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // location.href = e.target.getAttribute('href') + '?id=' + Pokemon_ID;
  console.log('changing URL to ' + e.target.getAttribute('href') + '?id=' + Pokemon_ID);
});
```

```html
<div id="right-btn" href="pokedex.php">text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
location.href += '?id=' + Pokemon_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you call changeUrl() within the onclick method you loose the context of this. This in changeUrl is not your div. Maybe you have to pass this into the method with `changeUrl(this)` or you just pass the href with `changeUrl(this.href)`.

Than use:

`function changeUrl(target){
location.href=target.href+'?id='+Pokemon_ID; 
}`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by CertainPerformance above, you are not passing the right arguments to you function to work correctly; Using you code as a reference, you can either pass the original event to you changeUrl() function, then use the e.target to get to your 'right-btn' element.

Javascript:

```
var Pokemon_ID = 1;

function changeUrl(e) {
     var href = e.target.getAttribute('href');
     console.log(href +'?id=' + Pokemon_ID);
     return false;
 }

 document.getElementById( 'right-btn' ).onclick = function(e) {
     changeUrl(e);
 };
```

HTML:

```
<div id="right-btn" href="pokedex.php">Click Me 4</div>
```

However, if you realy want to use **this** in your function to refer to the 'right-btn' element, then you can change the code to;

Javascript:

```
var Pokemon_ID = 1;

function changeUrl() {
     var href = this.getAttribute('href');
     console.log(href +'?id=' + Pokemon_ID);
     return false;
 }

 document.getElementById( 'right-btn' ).onclick = function(e) {
     changeUrl.call(e.target);
 };
```

The changes being the call in the event handler:
**changeUrl.call(e.target);**, which calls you function in the 'context' of the e.target, making the **this** in your **changeUrl()** function to the element. Then you can use the this as in **var href = this.getAttribute('href');**